# Combining the result of functors into a single module

Tags: ocaml

Say I have 2 functors that look something like:

```
module X (T : sig type t end) = struct
  type t = T.t
  ...
end

module Y (T : sig type t end) = struct
  type t = T.t
  ...
end
```

And I'd like to combine their result in a single module:

```
module M = struct
  include X(struct type t = int end)
  include Y(struct type t = int end)
end
```

Of course this doesn't work because I'm defining `t` twice inside of `M`. I know one way would be not to specify `t` inside of `X` or `Y` but I can't do that since then I can't write the signature that `X` or `Y` would produce because it involves `t`. What I wish I had is a way of somehow getting the signature of `X` or `Y` without the `t`.

EDIT: To make my question less abstract I'll give more context: I'm trying to unify in `Request.S` and `Response.S` in cohttp:

https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp/blob/master/cohttp/request.mli

https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp/blob/master/cohttp/response.mli

And here's where the module is combined:

https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp/blob/master/lwt/cohttp_lwt.ml#L36

Comment: Can't you just use `T.t` instead of `t` inside the signatures for `X` and `Y`?

Comment: Well the type of the resultant module must be specified as well: `module X ( T : sig type t end) : YYY`. So the problem is referring to `t` inside `YYY`.

Comment: I think you can still use `T.t` there.

Comment: P.S.: I've added the context to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:=` to remove `t` from `Y(T)`'s signature:

```
module X (T : sig type t end) = struct
  type t = T.t
end

module Y (T : sig type t end) = struct
  type t = T.t
end

module M = struct
  module T = struct type t = int end
  include X(T)
  include (Y(T) : module type of Y(T) with type t := T.t)
end
```